# Eclipse: How to tell if I am Running or Debugging a non-server application?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Eclipse will let you know if you started a server in Running or Debugging state.  For example:

[image]

Is there a way to get this same information for locally executed programs (i.e., desktop application, not web server application)?  I find often that I will be in the middle of testing my application and decide to set a breakpoint, but can't remember if I started via the Run or Debug icon.  In this case, I normally kill it and start again (for sure this time in Debug mode).  It would be useful to have this information available.  Am I just missing it somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply switch to the `Debug` perpective. The running application will be available. Then look in the `Debug` view : if you can expand using `+` your application and see running Threads, you are in debug mode. Otherwise, application is just 'running'.

Comment: I wish the status was displayed plain to see in any perspective -- but this works, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can look in debug perspective into Debug view. When debugging it shows the thread stack method invocation,

```
Example debugging,
```

[image: Debug]

```
Example NOT debugging,
```

[image]